# How to use python to ETL between databases?

Tags: python, postgresql, etl, psycopg2

Using psycopg2, I'm able to select data from a table in one PostgreSQL database connection and INSERT it into a table in a second PostgreSQL database connection.

However, I'm only able to do it by setting the exact feature I want to extract, and writing out separate variables for each column I'm trying to insert.

**Does anyone know of a good practice for either:**

- moving an entire table between databases, or
- iterating through features while not having to declare variables for every column you want to move
- or...?

Here's the script I'm currently using where you can see the selection of a specific feature, and the creation of variables (it works, but this is not a practical method):

```
import psycopg2

connDev = psycopg2.connect("host=host1 dbname=dbname1 user=postgres password=*** ")
connQa = psycopg2.connect("host=host2 dbname=dbname2 user=postgres password=*** ")
curDev = connDev.cursor()
curQa = connQa.cursor()

sql = ('INSERT INTO "tempHoods" (nbhd_name, geom) values (%s, %s);')

curDev.execute('select cast(geom as varchar) from "CCD_Neighborhoods" where nbhd_id = 11;')
tempGeom = curDev.fetchone()

curDev.execute('select nbhd_name from "CCD_Neighborhoods" where nbhd_id = 11;')
tempName = curDev.fetchone()

data = (tempName, tempGeom)

curQa.execute (sql, data)


#commit transactions
connDev.commit()
connQa.commit()

#close connections
curDev.close()
curQa.close()
connDev.close()
connQa.close()
```

One other note is that python allows the ability to explicitly work with SQL functions / data type casting, which for us is important as we work with the GEOMETRY data type. Above you can see I'm casting it to TEXT then dumping it into an existing geometry column in the source table - this will work with MSSQL Server, which is a huge feature in the geospatial community...

Comment: For migrating data between formats in python there's http://odo.readthedocs.org/

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to use ``pg_dump`` and **have** to use python

Comment: I think you need to learn more about psycopg. psycopg *definitely* lets you return multiple columns and rows in a single query. Look at [some examples](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html). If you don't like the positional tuples, see [`extras`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html). If your ETL is simple and you don't need strong decoupling or this is a one time operation, consider foreign data wrappers. FDW is a PostgreSQL mechanism that lets you interface with a remote database, even non-PG ones.

Comment: @fahaddaniyal I'm hoping to extend this over to MSSQL Server ... psycopg2 is good for PostgreSQL, but if python can be the intermediary, there's a good ETL solution in the works...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your solution (your solution and your question have a different order of statements) change the lines which start with '`sql =` ' and the loop before '`#commit transactions`' comment to

```
sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO "tempHoods" (nbhd_id, nbhd_name, typology, notes, geom) values '
sql_values = ['(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)']


data_values = []
# you can make this larger if you want
# ...try experimenting to see what works best
batch_size = 100 
sql_stmt = sql_insert + ','.join(sql_values*batch_size) + ';'
for i, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    data_values += row[:5]
    if i % batch_size == 0:
        curQa.execute (sql_stmt , data_values )
        data_values = []
if (i % batch_size != 0):
    sql_stmt = sql_insert + ','.join(sql_values*(i % batch_size)) + ';'
    curQa.execute (sql_stmt , data_values )
```

BTW, I don't think you need to commit.  You don't begin any transactions.  So there should not be any need to commit them.  Certainly, you don't need to commit a cursor if all you did was a bunch of selects on it.

Comment: So close! I tried working in your code, and was told by pyCharm to alter a few things, but here's what I've got so far http://pastebin.com/R8GWCnvm again, not doing anything in the FOR loop from what I can tell... Many thanks, Dmitry!!!

Comment: I've been trying to make this work, and while no errors are being thrown, nothing is committing to the database. When I print(sql_stmt, data_values) I get the following, which I think is wrong... ('INSERT INTO "temphoods" (nbhd_id, nbhd_name, typology, notes) values (%s, %s, %s, %s);', [37.0, 'Hilltop', None, None]) (for the 1st iteration of the batch...)

Comment: @mapBaker, you'd get the same errors with the version you had if you used these string parameters (ie, `%s` for `37.0`).  If your datum is actually a float, you should use `%f`.  And `None` will get inserted as `None` into Python strings if you use `%s`.  All I did was aggregate your loop into larger insert statements so that there would be less insert statements to run and less db round trips.  I didn't add any treatment of the actual data that you didn't already have.

Comment: Actually, assuming that `execute` does the right thing, passing `None` is probably ok.  It should get converted into `NULL`, but passing floats when you indicate that a string should be expected...  how that one fails will depend entirely on what `execute` does in `psycopg2`.... it may happen to fail silently.

Comment: Data type doesn't seem to have any affect on using %s when using the method in my original post... all data comes across just fine... hmmm...

Comment: Can you set the batch size to 1 and compare first lines of printouts of `print(sql, data)` in your loop vs `print(sql_stmt, data_values)` in my loop?

Comment: So I've gotten it to work by adding a connQa.commit()  - BUT - it only inserts the correct # of record (78) when the batch size is 1 - when I set the batch size to anything else it doesn't seem to be emptying the data_values array - it just keeps adding to it... so batch size of 20 creates 801 records and a batch size of 80 produces 3081 records... Thanks again for helping me out with this, Dmitry!!! I've also updated my pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/R8GWCnvm

Comment: The `if (i % batch_size != 0):` should be AFTER the loop.  Its purpose is to insert remaining values.  So if you have 107 values and your batch size is 20, you'd have 5 batches of 20 and then 1 batch (after the loop) of 7.  In the pastebin, the if statement is inside the loop (has the same indentation as the insides of the loop).  Is this a copy and paste error or is it how you are running it?

Comment: I think you nailed it - That was the issue - I'll do some testing of a bigger dataset tomorrow - also want to put a bounty on this and have you collect if possible... I can't thank you enough for the help!!!

Comment: Np, btw, I just moved the initial setting of `sql_stmt` outside the loop.  There is no need to reconstruct it every time inside the loop.  The only time it changes is when you are inserting the remaining values after the loop.

Comment: You've solved a huge problem here - thank you yet again - I've given your answer a bounty (100pts) which is the LEAST I can do to thank you for your solution!!! I just loaded our ~290,000 record address master file and it took LESS TIME than FME takes (the commercial solution) - now that I can read/write posgresql (and postgis) and mssql (AND mssql spatial) this will save  us a lot of money that we're currently paying for FME, etc... THANK YOU AGAIN DMITRY!!!

Comment: No prob.  But I guess most of the credit goes to Python as a language.  I've liked it for many years now.  This isn't really a forum for Python advocacy, but I will say that it's not uncommon to see people surprised at how compactly and quickly things can get done in it.  There are many sources for this cartoon, but this was the quickest I could find: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/d3/31/a2/d331a269b2f88ad7c0576666e27eb6f7.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Here's my updated code based on Dmitry's brilliant solution:

```
import psycopg2

connDev = psycopg2.connect("host=host1 dbname=dpspgisdev user=postgres password=****")
connQa = psycopg2.connect("host=host2 dbname=dpspgisqa user=postgres password=****")
curDev = connDev.cursor()
curQa = connQa.cursor()

print "Truncating Source"
curQa.execute('delete from "tempHoods"')
connQa.commit()
#Get Data
curDev.execute('select  nbhd_id, nbhd_name, typology, notes, cast(geom as varchar) from "CCD_Neighborhoods";') #cast geom to varchar and insert into geometry column!
rows = curDev.fetchall()


sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO "tempHoods" (nbhd_id, nbhd_name, typology, notes, geom) values '
sql_values = ['(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] #number of columns selecting / inserting


data_values = []

batch_size = 1000 #customize for size of tables... 

sql_stmt = sql_insert + ','.join(sql_values*batch_size) + ';'

for i, row in enumerate(rows, 1):

            data_values += row[:5] #relates to number of columns (%s)
            if i % batch_size == 0:
                curQa.execute (sql_stmt , data_values )
                connQa.commit()
                print "Inserting..."
                data_values = []

if (i % batch_size != 0):
    sql_stmt = sql_insert + ','.join(sql_values*(i % batch_size)) + ';'
    curQa.execute (sql_stmt, data_values)
    print "Last Values..."
    connQa.commit()





# close connections
curDev.close()
curQa.close()
connDev.close()
connQa.close()
```

Comment: If you really only have a few rows, sure.  Otherwise, I'd use 1 insert for all the rows.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich That's the key to my whole process right there - if you know any / could point me to some examples of how to do that, I'd be set (I'm sharpening my python skills as I go, but haven't come across that in any examples I've seen so far... ) Thank you!!!

Comment: I mean use the sql statement which inserts multiple values.  As in "insert into TABLENAME (COLNAME1, COLNAME2, ..COLNAMEn) values (val, val, ..., val), (val, val, ..., val), (val, val, ..., val), .... , (val, val, ..., val)".  You can construct the beginning of the statement and then progressively build up values in a loop. And execute them with 100 or 1000 (or whatever your testing shows up works best) values at a time.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich ah that is a big help... let me try that out and report back. Thank you again!

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich worked on this too long today and still back at the last script I posted in my answer above... if you have any thoughts on how to work with that, I'd greatly appreciate... stuck on extra ' and [ hanging around... again, python skills sharpening slowly... thanks for anything else you could add!